# New-Object -ComObject -Servername

Tags: powershell

I wanted to know in PowerShell if there is a way `New-Object -ComObject` can be run against a **remote server** like how it's possible natively in VBScript `WScript.CreateObject("COM Server", "RemoteServerName")`.

If not, is there an option without having to rely on PS Remoting technologies?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to instantiate remote COM objects via `New-Object`. You should be able to get the desired result via the [`GetTypeFromProgID()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e29bzzws.aspx) and [`CreateInstance()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx) methods, though:

```
$server = 'RemoteServerName'
$type   = [Type]::GetTypeFromProgID('COM Server', $server, $true)
if ($type) {
    $obj = [Activator]::CreateInstance($type)
}
```

[[source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/5286b020-a559-4ca0-9aa4-d27b2b28bc24/newobject-comobject-xy-computername-remotebox?forum=winserverpowershell)]